# Using laptop's camera in emulated enviroment for image processing

Tags: raspbian, camera

Sorry if title is a bit crowded but i'm kinda new to this. I'm a student trying to submit project but because of the pandemic we have to work separately. Project is a personnel recognition system which uses image processing. So my friend has all the hardware and i have to help him with what i got so i emulated raspberry pi in my laptop. I looked up some tutorials for image processing but i can't even access my laptop's camera from this emulated environment. I'm new to this so i can't do much for solving problems.

I tried:

Installing OpenCV yet i can't even open GUI and my terminal doesn't recognize OpenCV related commands.

Installing a app called Processing yet it doesn't even run.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Running Raspberry OS under emulation will not give you access to the Pi Camera on the hardware doing the emulation. I'd suggest you ask your friend to provide you with a collection of the images you are trying to recognise. Then write your Python code on your PC in Python. If you are careful the Python code should port easily over to your friend's Raspberry Pi.